# Result of committed Sequelize transaction is "undefined"

Tags: node.js, sql-server, transactions, sequelize.js

I am using a Sequelize transaction that returns successfully, however, the result is undefined. As stated in the documentation:

```
.then(function (result) {
  // Transaction has been committed
  // result is whatever the result of the promise chain returned to the transaction callback
```

Result should contain stuff!

My code works and updates the database successfully, and enters the `.then` block, yet result logs as "undefined".

```js
return sequelize.transaction(t => {
        return createUser(body, {transaction: t})
        .then(user => {
            if (user != null) {
                return createSetup({"user_id" : user.dataValues.id}, {transaction: t})
                .then(setup => {
                    console.log("setup was created")
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    throw new Error("the setup key was not created successfully... reverting transaction 2")
                })
            }
            else {
                throw new Error("no return value from creating user");
            }
        })
        .catch(err => {
            throw new Error("Failed to create user")
        })
    })
    .then(result => {
        console.log(result) //this returns undefined
        res.status(200).send({
            success: true,
            message: "The user was successfully created.",
        })
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log("error")
        res.status(400).send({
            success: false,
            message: error
        })
    })
})
```

I really want the result of the `user` object, but no matter what I do, it remains undefined. I have tried with and without returns on my subsequent functions within the transaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was under the assumption that

`return createUser(body, {transaction: t})`

would be "the result of the promise chain returned to the transaction callback

However, I needed to also return the user object in order to get it in `result`

```js
return sequelize.transaction(t => {
        return createUser(body, {transaction: t})
        .then(user => {
            if (user != null) {
                return createSetup({"user_id" : user.dataValues.id}, {transaction: t})
                .then(setup => {
                    //this line is necessary to get the value in the result of the transaction
                    return user, setup
                })
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.then(setup => {
                    return { user, setup }
                })
```

Comment: try to refactor your code with async/await.It's really difficult to read all this nested blocks of then/catch.